# How to make an already existing process raise events, in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, events

I want to make an already-existing process be able to raise events, via the 'EnableRaisingEvents' property.
It works fine for processes I start directly from the code, but when I try to do so for an already-existing process, I get a Win32 exception.

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("prog_name");
if (pname.Length != 0)
{
Process proc = pname[0];
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

This gives me the following message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: Access is denied

Comment: As can be seen by the duplicate, this generally works. You seem to have a permission problem of some kind instead (most likely the process you're trying to get events from is running as admin (privileged) and the yours is not). Make sure you fix this first, possibly by asking another or altered question.

Comment: @MickyD You are right. Messed that up. Sorry, Jack.

Comment: @Fildor not a problem good sir :)